# switch statement doesnt execute in function call

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get input from users that will be used in a function call `channel` that I created. In the `start` function I called function `channel` however it doesnt execute the function called and end the code there with printed selected channel.

```
# global vars
channelArr = ['1','2']

# func channel 1
def getChOne():
    print('Do something with channel 1')

# func channel 2
def getChTwo():
    print('Do something with channel 2')

# func channel
def channel(arg):
    switcher = { 
        1: lambda: getChOne(),
        2: lambda: getChTwo(),
    }
    return switcher.get(arg, lambda: "Invalid Channel")

# func start
def start():
    # get input
    print('\n')
    inputChannel = input('Channel 1 to 2: ')

    # check input 
    if (inputChannel.strip() in channelArr):
        print('Selected Channel:', inputChannel.strip())
        channel(inputChannel.strip())      
    else:
        exit()

# init app
if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    # call func start
    start()
```

Comment: `return switcher.get(arg, lambda: "Invalid Channel")` --> `return switcher.get(int(arg), lambda: "Invalid Channel")
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues here.

1. Your code does call `channel()` but it returns a lambda which you never use (call)
2. In your `switcher` dict keys are `int` and you pass `str` as argument (i.e. the lambda returned in 1. is always the one with `Invalid Channel`.
3. because in the if statement you check that user input is in `channelArr`, normally (i.e. if you fix the keys in `switcher`) there should be no need to use `get()` with fall-back value).
4. Actually you don't need lambda in `swithcher`

```
# func channel 1
def getChOne():
    print('Do something with channel 1')

# func channel 2
def getChTwo():
    print('Do something with channel 2')

# func channel
def channel(arg):
    switcher = { 
        '1': getChOne,
        '2': getChTwo,
    }
    return switcher.get(arg, lambda: print("Invalid Channel"))

# func start
def start():
    inputChannel = input('Channel 1 to 2: ').strip()
    print('Selected Channel:', inputChannel)
    channel(inputChannel)()  # call the function  

if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    # call func start
    start()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way to make a switch statement.

First define the switch function:

```
def switch(v): yield lambda *c: v in c
```

Then use it as a single-iteration for-loop where the loop variable is the case() function:

```
inputChannel = input('Channel 1 to 2: ').strip()
print('Selected Channel:', inputChannel)

for case in switch(inputChannel):

    if case('1'):
        print('Do something with channel 1')
        break

    if case('2'):
        print('Do something with channel 2')
        break
else:
   print('Invalid Channel')
```